# Calculate percentage error of pendulum

Tags: binomial-theorem, percentages

I am currently stuck on a question I have been given for a pendulum percentage error. The question is:
$$
T=2π\sqrt{L}/g
$$
Calculate the percentage error if your measurement of length is $5$% high and $g=9.81$.

What confuses me here is I have not been given a measurement for length or time, but I have been given gravity and actual length.

Any help would be great, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are expected to compute $\frac {\Delta T}{T}$ as a function of $\frac {\Delta L}L$ by taking the derivative.  Then you are given $\frac {\Delta L}{L}=0.05$